# How to View Microsoft documents using WinForms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser, ms-office

I need to be able to view a file (.doc, docx, .pdf, .txt,.....ect) in the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser (C# Visual Studio 2008) on a system that **does not** have office installed on it.  How do I do that? Can it be done?  I viewed many of the documentation that are out there regarding this and most all have office installed already.  I just need to be able to preview the documents, not modify them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in general. The way a browser displays an Office Document (or any other kind of document) is to run the application that created it - in this case, Office.

There are various tools which can render Office documents as HTML. You may be able to use those. One that I see mentioned frequently is [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/), though I have not used it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this using just the WebBrowser.

If you've seen the WebBrowser open a Word doc before, it's because Office was installed on the system, and it was using the Office ActiveX control to view it.

Some alteratives:

Programmatically upload the document to Office Live, then navigate the web browser to it. Office Live now has "Word in a web browser" functionality, [check it out here](http://www.officelive.com/en-us/).

Comment: Can I use it like a regular object?  Just make a Reference to it and add a using statement?  Is it redistributable?

Comment: You'll have to do some research. See how you can program against Office Live (or alternately, Google Docs). Both support MS Office documents via a web browser.